# How can I automatically respond to a password prompt via the command line?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-line, terminal

I'm looking to respond to a password prompt in the linux terminal. I know how to do this with `echo` and a non-password prompt. For example, let's say `whatsyourname.sh` prompted me for a string with my name after being ran, but didn't allow my name to be passed as an argument in the inital command. I would do the following:

```
echo -e "dan" | ./whatsyourname.sh
```

However, if I ran a command that asked me for a **password** after being ran, the following does not work:

```
echo -e "supersecurepassword" | sudo apt-get update
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that the characters are hidden while a password is being input in the command line. How would I respond to a password prompt within the inital command?

Comment: expect/send should work... it works for password prompts for dial up ppp connections, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `sudo -S`

Explaining -S - `man sudo`

> -S, --stdin
>                    Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the standard input instead of
>                    using the terminal device.  The password must be followed by a newline character.

Simple,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "notsecure" | sudo -S apt-get update
```

Variable,

```
#!/bin/bash
pass="notsecure"
echo $pass | sudo -S apt-get update
```

Lets still type it,

```
#!/bin/bash
read -s -p "[sudo] sudo password for $(whoami): " pass
echo $pass | sudo -S apt-get update
```

Explaining -s and -p - `help read`

> -r    do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
>
> -s    do not echo input coming from a terminal

Handy if you make a script that logs into multiple servers to view `route -n` for example.